# Database security through stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do stored procedures prevent SQL injection?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127/do-stored-procedures-prevent-sql-injection)

I'm curious about some database security techniques I've been learning in class recently.
Namely, I have implemented a SQL Server 2008R2 with stored procedures that a connection user can execute...
I continually get a server error processing url when attempting injection attacks and my DB tables remain untouched - I have read that a stored procedure is not a defense against injection - are more complex injections required to break it or are there reasons why simple drop table, list client, etc. injections are failing?
examples:

```
a';DROP TABLE CreditCard; SELECT * FROM Client WHERE 't' = 't

x' AND 1=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CreditCard); --
```

results are essentially:

```
exec sp_GetUser 'x' AND 1=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Client); --' , 'monkey'
```

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.

Here's the login stored procedure, incase that has some influence over why I'm getting the results I am.

```
USE [CIS413]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetUser] 

    @UserName varchar(50), @Password varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT userName from users where userName = @UserName and userPass = @Password
END
```